# Trying to create a 5 column table from a multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I'm running my code and it makes sense but doesn't work. I have a multidimensional array. I want the [0] index to be the text that's placed in the column and I want that also to have a link. I'm trying to do 5 columns across and the rest down but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
var cArray = [
  ['Cell Name 1','info','info'],
  ['Cell Name 2','info','info'],
  ['Cell Name 3','info','info']
];

  $('#cTable').append('<tbody></tbody>');
  $('#cTable').append('<tbody></tbody>');

  for (var i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++){
    if(i % 5 === 0){
        $('#cTable tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
    }
    $('#cTable tbody tr').append('<td>'+cArray[i][0]+'</td>');
  }

<table id="cTable" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4"></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
  if (i % 5 === 0) {
    $('#cTable tbody').append('<tr></tr>');
  }
  $('#cTable tbody tr:last').append('<td>' + cArray[i][0] + '</td>');
}
```

Try appending to the last tr as `$('#cTable tbody tr:last').append()` will append to all of the tr elements that match your selector.

https://jsfiddle.net/b8ysa6mx/

Comment: I knew it!... i thought the same thing. That worked. How do I add a link to the text... is there an easy way. Basically I want to add i as a class in an anchor. so it would look like this: <a href="#" class="but_c0">Cell Name 1</a> <-- where the 0 is the index

Comment: $('#cTable tbody tr:last').append('<td><a href="#" class="but_'+i+'">' + cArray[i][0] + '</a></td>');

Comment: Something like that?

Comment: Yea.... that's the way I would do it. I was wondering if there was a cool, javascript/jquery way of doing it. A shortcut of sorts.

Comment: if you didnt want to pass a string you would need to create each of the elements as jquery objects and append them using append/appendTo

Comment: $('<td/>').append($('<a/>').text(cArray[i][0]).addClass('but_c' + i)).appendTo($('#cTable tbody tr:last'))

Comment: Either way works just different ways of doing the same thing